# Should we explicitly cast from Lua's luaL_checkinteger() et al?

Tags: c, lua, lua-api, lua-5.3

Lua 5.3 deprecates [luaL_checkint](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_checkint), [luaL_checklong](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_checklong), [luaL_optint](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_optint), [luaL_optlong](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_optlong), which were just convenience macros calling `luaL_{check|opt}integer`.

While we can still use them (because of `-DLUA_COMPAT_5_2`), they aren't mentioned in the [user manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/) and we're advised to use `luaL_{check|opt}integer` "with a type cast".

Now, I'm not an expert in C and I was wondering:

1. Is a cast needed in simple cases like the following?

   ```
   int i;
   i = (int)luaL_checkinteger(L, 1);
   ```
2. If a cast isn't needed here, where **is** it needed?
3. Why were those deprecated macros born in the first place if we can do without them? In other words: what did they serve?
4. Aren't we losing "documentation" by not having the words "int"/"long" embedded in the function name?

Comment: Perhaps better suited to be discussed in the Lua mailing list.

Comment: @lhf: Thanks. I've just emailed my question there. I'll summarize here any answers I get there.

Comment: For the time being, people can read the mailing list thread [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/115068).

Answer (score 1):

1. C does not require such a cast.
2. Basically, if you want the number to behave *exactly* like a specific C type, then you should cast it to one. If you're fine with it behaving like a `lua_Integer`, then you do not need to cast it.

   So if you want the range of the value to be within the range of `int`, then you should cast it when you pull the integer out of Lua. If you try to pass it to a variadic function like `printf` without the cast, it will get the full range of the `lua_Integer`, rather than the range of `int`. That may be what you want, but if it isn't, you need the cast.
3. They were added because pre-Lua 5.3 numbers were always `double`s. As such, to get an integer of any kind *required* a cast. It's better to cast from `double` to `int` directly than from `double` to `long` to `int`. Once Lua formally got an exact integer type, that need became less important.

   Notice that there was never a `lua_checkfloat`. The same reason applies.
4. That's open to interpretation. But since integers are first-class values in Lua 5.3, I'd say it's better to be able to fetch the integer exactly as Lua sees it. If the user wants to cast it to a different integer type, that's up to them.

   As for being better documentation, this isn't C++11. There's no `auto x = lua_checkinteger(...);` here. The type you're using must be explicitly stated when you're using it. If you're assigning it to a variable, it is clear to all what you are doing. If you're explicitly casting it, then again it's clear what you're doing. If you're passing it to a function, all you need do is look at the argument list to see what it is being converted into.